# 3rd party terrain editor

Tags: terrain

I am looking for a good application for generating 3d terrains (really allowing generation and then some user-editing) . After a google search, I found many, but I need one that can export the entire terrain as a mesh. This, I was unable to find. (I need either a .obj .fbx or .3ds output) The size of the file that is written and the price of the program are not major factors in my decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net) you can convert from a lot of formats to .obj
I think that the usability of the tool should be your first priority as the formats can then be converted by your application.